# What is the Laravel way for having different types of users? model/migration unclear

Tags: laravel

I'm building an app where I have 2 types of Users, Agents and Clients.
While Clients don't need to input a lot of info, Agents are asked quite a bit to register.

To avoid a lot of empty cells, I initially thought to build 2 Models and Auth against the one I'd need. But that is advised against.

My question is which route would be considered best practice:

- Build one User model with a lot of nullable fields
- Somehow extend Users with Agents so Clients take up the Users table and Agents take up the 2
- Something else entirely

I've only rarely extended a Class when working with PHP and going through the Laravel docs it's unclear which way's expected from me for best support...
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: "But that is advised against" by who?

Comment: Nothing wrong in making seperate User Models you will need to register seperate Auth gaurds to authenticate.

Comment: In my opinion, user is user - it have password, username and role. Other information you can store in separate tables depends on role.

Comment: You should have `users` table, as @Zohaib said, and just use a [morphable relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships), so you can define what type of user it is. After doing so, you can store data in a separate table.

Comment: @krisgjika A lot of people, myself included. In my experience, having multiple Models/Tables for what are essentially the same thing (A `User` has an `Email` and `Password`, an `Admin` has an `Email` and `Password`, and so on) is a pain... A `User` is a `User`, an `Admin` is a `Role` that a `User` can have. If an `Admin` has additional details, it can be properties on the `Role` table, or a separate joined table. You're correct that it _can_ be done (via the article you posted and your answer), but ultimately most people lean towards a "Single point of truth" approach i.e. single model `User`.

Comment: @TimLewis agreed, that is how I also would usually handle this. However in a question asking about options I don't think it's fair to disregard one of the options completely. Each option has it's pros and cons. If you would store your admin specific fields on the role, i.e. the pivot table of users and roles you also need to be very careful managing that. What if I attach the same role twice? What if I attach two roles to the same user? Do I want to lose the admin fields if I detach the relation? Given the information, or lack of, I think both options are viable.

Comment: @krisgjika Of course! It definitely is an option, I'm in no way trying to discredit your answer; it's a perfectly valid solution. The unfortunate reality is that, while downvotes are typically used to indicate inaccuracies (i.e. a question is "wrong"), they are often also used as a "agreement" indicator. It seems a lot of people disagree with the approach your answer takes... The pros and cons of both approaches are there and would need to be handled, but that's an entirely separate thing. Anyway, just trying to answer your subquestion ("advised against [...]"), sorry for the wave of downvotes

Comment: @krisgjika I also do think your answer is valid, but answering question in this platform (SO) made me realize that most people (authors) want a "copy-paste" of some sort, and I do not answer in that way, I do show the "best" or mostly wide used solution (or better solution) instead of the easy "you can do 1+1+1+1+1 if you want" to earn points or similar, I prefer saying "you can do 4+1 and done, and most devs will do this and you should follow standards". Some authors like those answers, others say they don't care and downvote because it is not replying exactly as they want. You did reply good

Answer (score -4):

Article going into more details: https://medium.com/@nayeemdev/how-to-create-multi-authentication-with-multiple-table-in-laravel-dbc43e229f9f

Create a new guard for your authenticatable model

```php
'guards' => [

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'agent'  => [
          'driver'  => 'session',
          'provider' => 'agents',
        ],

 ],


 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'agents' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\Agent::class,
        ],
]
```

Create controller to authenticate agents

```php
class AgentLoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function guard()
    {
     return Auth::guard('agent');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.agent_login');
    }
 }
```

Can also create middleware to protect agent routes from being accessed by clients

Comment: Why have different authenticatable agents when the user did not mention this at all? Doing this is way more complex than the relation issue itself... totally not recommended

Comment: "To avoid a lot of empty cells, I initially thought to build 2 Models ...", implying two tables, "... and Auth against the one I'd need." While this solution might be more complex setting up, it's easier to use latter than creating relations and keeping track of them all the time.

Comment: And for each new role you need to add new guard and a lot of other stuff. Bellissimo :)

Comment: Roles have nothing to do here. The solution is for cases when your authentication models have different fields. If you need your "agents" to do different things based on their role, you can attach roles/permissions to them. Feel free to provide your own solution using relations ;)